# Как преобразовать обьект в строку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как на преобразовать обьект например

```
const testConvert = {
    page1: 'Первая страница',
    page2: 'Вторая страница',
    page3: 'Третья страница',
 };
```

На выходе должна быть строка `"page1: Первая страница, page2: Вторая страница, page3: Третья страница"`.

`toString()` не работает, т.к. работает только с примитивами
`JSON.stringify(testConvert)` тоже не подходит.

Нужен просто строковый формат.

Comment: Чем жe не подходит?) `console.log( JSON.stringify(testConvert).replace(/[{}"]/g, "").replace(/([,:])/g, "$1 ") );`

Comment: Как для начинающего "JS ника", не совсем понятная запись(((

Answer (score 5):

```
const testConvert = {
    page1: 'Первая страница',
    page2: 'Вторая страница',
    page3: 'Третья страница'
 };

Object.entries(testConvert).map(([k,v])=>`${k}: ${v}`).join(', ')
```

Comment: Очень лаконичный метод, единственное, что в первый раз вижу такую запись в map как ([k,v]), не подскажите как этот вид записи называется и где о нем можно прочитать, заранее спасибо.

Comment: `([k,v])=>\`${k}: ${v}\`` это эквивалентно `(row) => { const [k,v] = row; return \`${k}: ${v}\`; }` то есть в функцию приходит первый параметр, который состоит из одной пары ключ-значение. Я его определяю как параметр-массив и получаю как первые два элемента массива в разные аргументы.

Comment: И разумеется, `const [k,v] = row;` эквивалентно `const k = row[0], v = row[1];`

Comment: @AlexandrMandryka  То есть, даже так было бы более понятно `Object.entries(testConvert).map(e=>\`${e[0]}: ${e[1]}\`).join(', ')` но так написано в ответе, мне больше нравится.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо. Это называется Деструктурирующее присваивание.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const testConvert = {
  page1: 'Первая страница',
  page2: 'Вторая страница',
  page3: 'Третья страница'
};

let result_str = "";
for (item in testConvert) {
  if (result_str != "") result_str += ", ";
  result_str += item + ": '" + testConvert[item] + "'";
}

console.log(result_str);
```

Если кавычки не нужны, можно легко убрать.

Comment: Спасибо, как для начинающего, очень понятно все. Спасибо.